# typeface.js - is not "rewriting"

Tags: jquery, typeface, typeface.js

How can it be that `typeface.js` doesn't "rewrite" when you press a new `href`?

If you remove `typeface-js` from the class it works.

Live link: http://temp.electrobeat.dk/typeface.php

## updated function:

```
            function generate_menu(page){
                var menu = {
                    posting : {
                        title : 'Posting'
                    },
                    account : {
                        title : 'Account'
                    }
                };
                
                var elm = $('#div_menu').empty();
                for(var key in menu){
                    (function(key){
                        $('<a class="typeface-js menu '+(key == page ? 'menu_active':'')+'" href="#'+key+'">'+menu[key].title+'</a>').appendTo(elm)
                            .click(function(){
                                generate_menu(key);
                            });
                    })(key);
                }
                _typeface_js.initialize();
            };
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script src="typeface-0.15.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="arial_bold.typeface.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function generate_menu(page){
                    var menu = {
                        posting : {
                            title : 'Posting'
                        },
                        account : {
                            title : 'Account'
                        }
                    };
                    
                    var elm = $('#div_menu').empty();
                    for(var key in menu){
                        (function(key){
                            $('<a class="typeface-js menu '+(key == page ? 'menu_active':'')+'" href="#'+key+'">'+menu[key].title+'</a>').appendTo(elm)
                                .click(function(){
                                    generate_menu(key);
                                });
                        })(key);
                    }
                };
                
                generate_menu('posting');
            });
        </script>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            #div_menu {
                background:#ff0000;
                padding:5px;
            }
            
            .menu {
                font-family:arial;
                font-size:14px;
                color:#e8f5ff;
                font-weight:bold;
                border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:1px 2px 2px 2px;
                margin:0px 2px 0px 2px;
            }
            
            .menu_active {
                color:#07447c;
                border-bottom:3px solid #e8f5ff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="div_menu"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: the menu bar has to regenerate with focus on the current menu href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're removing the elements and then adding them again, but typeface.js only runs once on the page. If you are doing this you need to manually retrigger typeface.js's method, which might be:

```
_typeface_js.initialize();
```

Put this (or whichever method it turns out to be) in your generate_menu method after attaching the elements.

Comment: how can you retrigger the method

Comment: Updated with a possibility. You'll have to look inside the typeface.js source code to find the best way of doing this.

Comment: Have updated my question with a updated generate_menu().. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Okay. Reading in the source code, this line is stopping it from working: `// quit if this function has already been callee ¬ if (arguments.callee.done) return;` - basically typeface.js is broken and you should use Typekit or something else to do what you want to do.

Comment: is Typekit a better script? but Typekit costs money

Comment: As I can see typeface has a far better rendering.. after escaping the line you mentioned the script works! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
_typeface_js.renderDocument();
```

http://typeface.neocracy.org/forum/topic.html?id=325

Answer (score -1):

You must cancel the default event propagation when clicking the link:

```
.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    generate_menu(key);
    return false;
});
```

What happens is that no matter what code is executing when you click the menu links, the browser goes to their `href` which is "#".